# How to flatten array on joined snowflake data

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-warehouse

I currently have this query that filters for the latest record by it's `updated_at` column and looks for rows that have a specific type. I'm attempting to flatten the array so that I can extract that specific object data but I don't think I'm using `lateral flatten()` correctly.

The row has data that looks like so:

```
[{ "token": "1234", type: "STORE" }, { "token": "4567", type: "MERCHANT" }]
```

Snowflake Query:

```
with unique_merchants as (
  select 
    updated_at, 
    aliases, 
    merchant_token, 
    identity_token, 
    row_number() over (
      partition by merchant_token 
      order by 
        updated_at desc
    ) as row_number 
  from 
    table.PUBLIC.business_info
) 
select 
  identity_token, 
  merchant_token,
  aliases
from
  unique_merchants 
  inner join table.PUBLIC.stores on table.PUBLIC.stores.parent_token = merchant_token, 
  lateral flatten(aliases) as obj
where 
  value:type = 'STORE' 
  and row_number = 1;
```

Right now this query gives me *half* of what I need. The output returns all rows that have an object of type `STORE` in it's `ALIAS` column. I'd like to be able to also extract the token from objects of type `STORE` but that's where I'm having trouble. I've tried exploding the row in the CTE that I created and also in the second `FROM` clause but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

To further simplify the query, it is possible to filter rows based on windowed function inside CTE:

```
with unique_merchants as (
  select updated_at, 
         aliases, 
         merchant_token, 
         identity_token
  from table.PUBLIC.business_info
  qualify row_number() over (partition by merchant_token order by updated_at desc)=1
)
select 
  identity_token, 
  merchant_token,
  aliases,
  obj.value:token:TEXT
from unique_merchants 
join table.PUBLIC.stores 
  on table.PUBLIC.stores.parent_token = merchant_token 
,lateral flatten(unique_merchants.aliases) as obj
where obj.value:type::TEXT = 'STORE';
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I needed by adding `value:token::string` in the select outside of the CTE.